# Is it possible to pass an argument to a model class's method in Django's template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a model called `UserProfile` defined as

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user       = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile_from_user')
    user_types = models.ManyToManyField(UserType, related_name='userprofiles_from_user_types', null=True, blank=True)

    def has_user_types(self, user_types):
        return self.user_types.filter(name__in=user_types).count()
```

`UserType` is defined as

```
class UserType(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('ad', 'administrator'   ), # 1
        ('mo', 'moderator'       ), # 2
        ('vi', 'viewer'          ), # 3
        ('pm', 'property manager'), # 4
        ('po', 'property owner'  ), # 5
        ('vm', 'vendor manager'  ), # 6
        ('ve', 'vendor'          ), # 7
        ('te', 'tenant'          ), # 8
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

I want to be able to use the `UserProfile`'s method `has_user_types()`. In a view, I would do something like

```
if user.profile.has_user_types(['ad', 'mo', 'pm']):
    # The user is any combination of an administrator, moderator, or property manager.
```

But can I do the same thing in the template? I am specifically checking for a few user types so I wanted to do something like

```
{% if user.profile.has_user_types(['te']) %}
```

I know I could simply define another method called `is_tenant()` in the model (that takes no argument), but I also wanted to check other user types and I was wondering if I could consolidate `has_user_types()`.

**Side question:** If Django's default template can't do it, then can [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) do it?

---

**Solution**

Thanks to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's help!

`custom_tags.py`:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def has_user_types(user_pk, *args):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)

    return user.profile.has_user_types(args)
```

template:

```
{% load has_user_types from custom_tags %}

{# I pass the pk because I want to be able to pass any user, not just request.user #}
{% has_user_types user.pk "te" as is_tenant %}
{% if is_tenant %}
    {# Show something #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Write a [custom filter or template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that checks for them.

Comment: Suppose I write a custom template tag that can take any number of arguments (for the user types). So I can use it like `{% has_user_types user "ad" "mo" "pm" %}`. But what I really want to do is simply have the tag return `True` or `False`. So is it possible to do something like `{% has_user_types user "te" as is_tenant %}` then do `{% if is_tenant %}...`?

Comment: "Setting a variable in the context" "Assignment tags"

Comment: Oops, I shouldn't have asked *Is it possible...*. I meant to ask *Should I* or is there a better way to do it? I was already reading the documentation on [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) when I wrote the first comment lol. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's sort of a clunky issue in the first place, so I'm not sure that I'd worry about how it looks at this point. Implement *something*, then worry about how it feels.

Comment: Ya, I got it working. Thanks for the help! Custom tags looked intimidating at first, but then I read the part about `simple_tag` lol.